# Why do I need default while accessing a structure?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I had this VB method which I converted to C#

```
Public Function GetToricData(ByRef SaveFileName As String) As ToricDataType
        Dim filenumber As Short
        Dim InString As String = ""
        filenumber = FreeFile()
        If System.IO.File.Exists(SaveFileName) Then
            With GetToricData
                FileOpen(filenumber, SaveFileName, OpenMode.Input)
                Input(filenumber, InString)
                If IsNumeric(InString) Then
                    .ToricAppDiam = Convert.ToDouble(InString)
                End If
                Input(filenumber, InString)
                If IsNumeric(InString) Then
                    .NumToricOpticZones = Convert.ToInt16(InString)
                End If
                FileClose(filenumber)
            End With
        Else
            With GetToricData
                .NumToricOpticZones = 20
                .ToricAppDiam = 3
            End With
            SaveToricData(SaveFileName, GetToricData)
        End If
    End Function
```

Post conversion to C# using Telerik Online Converter I got this

```
public static FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType GetToricData(ref string SaveFileName)
        {
            var title = ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0]).Title;
            FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType functionReturnValue =  default(FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType);
            //FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType functionReturnValue = new FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType();

            int filenumber = 0;
            string InString = "";
            filenumber = FileSystem.FreeFile();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(SaveFileName))
            {
                var _with38 = functionReturnValue;
                FileSystem.FileOpen(filenumber, SaveFileName, OpenMode.Input);
                FileSystem.Input(filenumber,ref InString);
                if (Information.IsNumeric(InString))
                {
                    _with38.ToricAppDiam = Convert.ToDouble(InString);
                }
                FileSystem.Input(filenumber,ref InString);
                if (Information.IsNumeric(InString))
                {
                    _with38.NumToricOpticZones = Convert.ToInt16(InString);
                }
                FileSystem.FileClose(filenumber);
            }
            else
            {
                var _with39 = functionReturnValue;
                _with39.NumToricOpticZones = 20;
                _with39.ToricAppDiam = 3;
                SaveToricData(ref SaveFileName, ref _with39);
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
```

**ToricDataType**  is defined as

```
 public struct ToricDataType
        {
            public double ToricAppDiam;
            public short NumToricOpticZones;
        }
```

I want to know that what is the significance of the line

> FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType functionReturnValue = 
>   default(FrontEndStructures.ToricDataType);

why did the online tool use **Default** keyword and why **new** keyword couldnt be used ?
As the class is a structure type and Structures are value types so where is the memory allocated (Stack or Heap ) and how data members are initialized ?

I am expecting a detail explanation on this and want to know that using **new** **operator** would help me achieve the same purpose or not ?

Comment: "As the class is a structure type".  Um, no.  A class is a class and a structure is a structure.  If you want a word that can refer to either then use "type".

Comment: "Structures are value types so where is the memory allocated".  Where is the memory ALWAYS allocated for value types?  It doesn't matter what value type it is.

Comment: "how data members are initialized".  The whole point of `default` is that it's the default value for the type.  Just like `Nothing` in VB, it's equivalent to populating the variable's stack memory with zeroes.  That means that ever field will also have the default value for it's type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# `null` is not quite the same as the VB `Nothing`.  In VB, `Nothing` means the default value for a type.  For a reference type that is a null reference and for a value type that is a value with all its fields set to default values. In C#, `null` means a null reference for reference types but cannot be used to initialise value types.  The `default` operator does the equivalent job of providing a default value for a value type.

Note also that, unlike VB, C# functions have no default return value.  In VB you can assign to the implicit local variable that is named after the function and that value will be returned if no explicit `Return` statement is hit.  In C#, you are obliged to explicitly return something, hence the additional local variable.  I would really suggest not using that implicit return in VB anyway.  Explicit returns make your code clearer.

EDIT: You can use the `new` keyword to create a new instance and have the same effect.  The one scenario where you must use `default` is when the type you pass it is a generic type parameter, in which case you normally won't know whether it is a reference type or value type.

Comment: what about using the new operator ?

Comment: so where is the memory allocated ?

Comment: As I commented on your question, it's a value type and value types are always stored in the same place.  You don't need me to tell you where that place is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i encountered this issue for the first time so asked. I knew that new operator allocates memory on heap whereas Structure is a value type so it uses stack. so when using new with a structure type where the memory would be created was a confusion.